# Why does the Air Force base need a dead galaxy professor?

Tags: dont-look-up

Calder is speaking on the phone with Dr. Oglethorpe about the comet that
is heading towards Earth and is expected to arrive in 6 months and 14 days.
The comet was discovered by Kate and Mindy, with Mindy doing the orbital
calculations.:

> Calder: I serve at the discretion of the president.
>
> Kate: Is this really happening?
>
> Calder:…and the **dead galaxy professor to Hickam Air Force base**.

Why does the Air Force base need a dead galaxy professor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The professor (Dr. Randall Mindy) is the one that made the discovery. At this point the President's advisors want to collect all of the people that know about the comet, firstly to confirm that it's a legitimate threat, and secondly to stop the unauthorised spread of information lest it cause a panic.

> **DR. CALDER:** *Whoah, whoah. This is classified information Dr. Oglethorpe. **I serve at the discretion of the President and her policy
> is all priority intel goes to her first.***
>
> **DR. OGLETHORPE:** *But if these numbers are right*
>
> **DR. CALDER:** *The administration’s policy is clear. Now let’s get the student and the dead galaxy Professor to Hickam Air Force Base
> now.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Don't look up: Final Screenplay](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/dont-look-up-2021.pdf)</sup></sub>

---

Note that he's a professor of dead galaxies, not a dead professor who studied galaxies.

> **RANDALL:** *Uh, hi, yes, Dr. Mindy. And no, PHD candidate Kate Dibiasky found it, I did the orbital calculations. I study um, trace
> gases in dead galaxies. I haven’t published in awhile so you probably
> haven’t heard of me - but that doesn’t matter obviously - sorry.*